# Is there any way to get the leading interval precision for a column through DBI in Perl?

Tags: perl, odbc, dbi

I need to be able to get the following column attributes in a perl script for a column in an ODBC table :

- SQL Type
- Precision
- Scale
- Interval Leading Precision
- TypeName
- Whether its signed or unsigned
- Nullability
- Whether it's case sensitive
- Whether it's auto-unique
- Updatability

Right now I'm using DBI, and it seems I can get [most](http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.33/ODBC.pm#ColAttributes) of this information, but I'm stumped with getting the interval leading precision. Does DBI expose this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That pod (which I wrote) is for SQLColAttributes. What happened is MS deprecated SQLColAttributes and replaced it with SQLColAttribute. BTW, there is a typo in the pod as that should by $sth not $dbh (I've just fixed that). ColAttributes is now superceded by DBI attributes in most cases e.g., [PRECISION](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.618/DBI.pm#PRECISION). You cannot pass the new SQLColAttribute types to SQLColAttributes with DBD::ODBC as it only knows about the ones that ODBC defined for SQLColAttributes and as ODBC allowed driver-specific attributes (for which DBD::ODBC could not possibly know the type of) it has to trap them and issue a "driver-specific column attributes not supported" message.

See [SQLColAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms713558%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) which lists all the values you can pass to ColAttribute. You'll have to look in the sql*.h header files for the values. However, I don't see an interval leading precision in the list. I do see that SQL_DESC_PRECISION says "For data types SQL_TYPE_TIME, SQL_TYPE_TIMESTAMP, and all the interval data types that represent a time interval, its value is the applicable precision of the fractional seconds component.". So I'm unsure what you mean by "interval leading precision".

What ODBC driver are you using?

Comment: in ODBC you get the interval leading precision through getDescField, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716251%28v=vs.85%29.aspx . I'm using an proprietary driver, but I want this to work for ODBC drivers in general in the future.

Comment: You could always supply a patch to me for adding support for SQLGetDescField. I'm a little pushed for time but I might find some time to add it myself.